# Process locked portion of file (Java)

Tags: java, locking

been pulling my hair out about this for ages!

Trying to put a lock on a text file ("test.txt") then read a line from the text file and release the lock.

I get the following error:

"Err: java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file"

See my code below:

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

```
    File file = new File("test.txt");
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);


    FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile("test.txt", "rw").getChannel();

    try{
        FileLock lock = channel.tryLock();

        System.out.println("Data: " + dis.readLine());

        lock.release();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Err: "+ex);
    }
    in.close();
}
```

It seems like a process is locking the file before it gets to the read operation?

Sorry for my ignorance, not been doing Java for long and ive tried looking for solutions elsewhere.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, you're locking it yourself, via the channel. So you can read from it via the channel (if you aquired the lock). But you're trying to read from it via `dis` ?

Comment: So i have to read from the channel?

Comment: yes you have, these are two different streams you opened.

Comment: So i have to put the information from "channel" into a buffer. Can i use a bufferedReader to do this?

Comment: You can extract a Channel object using FileOuputStream.getChannel(). Then you lock that channel and retrieve data with the reader you want. BUT it has to be on the same stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("test.txt", "rw");
FileChannel channel = raf.getChannel();

// .. do locking here ...

// wrap DataInputStream around existing, locked connection
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(raf.getFD()));
System.out.println("Data: " + dis.readLine());

// .. do unlocking here ...
```

Comment: getFD() method does not exist for RandomAccessFile

Comment: @Roalt - it sure does http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#getFD()

Answer (score 0):

can you also place the

> lock.release();

in the catch Block

```
try
{

} catch (Exception e)
{
if (lock != null )
     lock.release();
}
```

since you IOException is thrown while accessing the file, the file lock is not released.